# path not valid compress file with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compress file:

```
 [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory("E:\YYY Software\mmmm\file.csv","E:\YYY\aaa\file.zip")
```

but I get the error:

> Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "The directory name is invalid '

I think is due to is a file and not a directory?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell `5.0` onwards, `Compress-Archive` is available:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "E:\YYY Software\mmmm\file.csv" -DestinationPath "E:\YYY\aaa\file.zip"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have version 4 :-(